# libmpv intptr_t of an NSView

Tags: c, swift, mpv

I am trying to use libmpv in a swift project. I have everything linked up and am trying to follow the basic [example](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-examples/blob/master/libmpv/cocoa/cocoabasic.m).

The problem is, that to show a video, I have to pass an integer pointer (intptr_t) to the [wid command](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-wid). In Objective-C this would be done as the example above hints:

```
int64_t wid = (intptr_t) self->wrapper;
```

where wrapper is the wrapper view meant for the video player. However, as swift is not meant to be working with pointers, and the wrapper view is one as I understand, I do not know how to translate this to swift.

I tried casting the NSView to an `UnsafePointer` like this

```
let t = UnsafePointer(&view)
```

and then cast `t` to an `intptr_t` or `Int` but this conversion does not work. It says this value cannot be converted to the `Int`.
So how can I embed the video player in a swift view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need an int pointer, at all. The [`mpv_set_option() API`](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/libmpv/client.h#L868-L910) you're trying to call actually takes a `void *`. In Swift, this is bridged as `UnsafeRawPointer`.

I think you can just pass in `&view` directly, which should bridge to `UnsafeRawPointer` automatically. However, now you have to be careful, because you have to ensure that the lifetime your VC lasts at least as long as `mpv` needs it.

Comment: I think you are correct, at least I did as you suggested and I did not get any errors. However, the video still won't play but I don't think the problem lies with my asked question.